# Passing options to the draw function declaration in quil and clojure.

Tags: clojure, draw

I am a beginner in using Quil and Clojure and am attempting to draw some rectangles from some existing data structures. If I define the draw function to take a structure of some kind how do I pass the structure to draw using defsketch?

```
(defn draw [x]
  (stroke 80)
  (stroke-weight 3)
  (fill 23 181 100)
  (rect x x x x))

(defn create-sketch []
  "Automatically uses the given setup and draw functions. Magic."
  (defsketch example
    :setup setup
    :draw draw
    :size [2000 2000]))
```

In the code above (taken from one of Quil's examples) I could define draw to take a random parameter x which it would then use. I can't figure out how to pass in a parameter when defining the sketch. The `:draw draw` declaration as it is now works for a function with an empty parameter-list. I have tried every way I can think of to pass it in some x value. I'm not knowledgeable enough on what the problem actually is to be able to fix it.

Comment: What are the parameters you would like to pass and where would you want to define them?

Comment: @ponzao Well I would like to pass draw a sequence of items that I can use the rect function to display. I would want to just have a sequence of commands from the function that gets run on program entry that would end with create-sketch. That would involve giving create-sketch and defsketch the sequence which would then pass it to draw which I can't seem to do. [This](http://goo.gl/Csgvz) is what I am working on. Its hacky right now. run-project gets called from inside draw.

Comment: @ponzao nevermind figured it out. Needed `:draw (partial draw term-list)` instead of `:draw (draw term-list)`.

Answer (score 3):

quil `draw` takes no arguments. The `partial` trick shown in the comments works if you always draw the same list of rectangles.
If you want to have an animation `draw` must access a mutable state (eg an `atom`).

Comment: For Quil (as in Processing) there is the `millis` function that returns the number of milliseconds since the sketch started. ( https://github.com/quil/quil/blob/master/src/quil/core.clj#L2257 ) This can also be used for animations, in the case where you don't want to add your own (more) mutable state.